# Stop Solr gracefully when it running in docker

Tags: bash, solr, docker, dockerfile

I am running a solr in docker container

My docker `ENTRYPOINT` is `$SOLR_HOME/bin/solr start ${options}`

currently when I am running `docker stop <container Id>` its kill the process but solr stops incorrectly

In order to stop Solr correctly we need to run : `$SOLR_HOME/bin/solr stop`

How do I config docker to call `solr stop` command when `docker stop <container Id>` is executed?

Comment: asking the same question :)

Answer (score 5):

When running `$SOLR_HOME/bin/solr stop`, the kernel sends a SIGQUIT signal to the process. To duplicate this in docker, you need to run `docker kill --signal="SIGQUIT" <ContainerName>` rather than docker stop. Docker Stop sends a SIGTERM signal by default.